# How to make IntToBin function return 96bits binary number?

Tags: delphi, binary

I have this function to convert **Integer** to **Binary**.

Delphi code:

```
function IntToBin(IValue : uInt; NumBits : word = 64) : string;
  var RetVar : string;
  i,ILen : byte;
 begin
    RetVar := '';

    case NumBits of
       32 : IValue := dword(IValue);
       16 : IValue := word(IValue);
       8  : IValue := byte(IValue);
     end;

   while IValue <> 0 do
    begin
       Retvar := char(48 + (IValue and 1)) + RetVar;
       IValue := IValue shr 1;
    end;

    if RetVar = '' then
      Retvar := '0';

    Result := RetVar;
end;
```

if IValue = 5439788

it returns:

10100110000000100101100

What I should change to make it return ***96bits*** binary number?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not provide a declaration of `uInt`, I will presume it is declared as:

```
Type
  uInt = record
    lowU,highU: UInt64;
  end;
```

And the binary conversion could look like this:

```
function IntToBin(IValue : uInt; NumBits : word = 64) : string;
var
  b: Integer;
const
  HiLo: array[boolean] of Char = ('0','1');

  procedure _IntToBin64(Value: UInt64; num : Integer);
  var
    i: Integer;
    mask: UInt64;
  begin
   mask := UInt64(1) shl (num-1);
   for i := num downto 1 do
   begin
     Inc(b);
     Result[b] := HiLo[(Value and mask) <> 0];
     mask := mask shr 1;
   end;
  end;

begin
  if (NumBits = 0) or (NumBits > 128) then
    Exit('0');
  SetLength(Result,NumBits);
  b := 0;
  if (NumBits > 64) then
  begin
    _IntToBin64(IValue.highU,NumBits-64);
    NumBits := NumBits - 64;
  end;
  _IntToBin64(IValue.lowU,NumBits);
end;
```

This will do a conversion of a number up to 128 bits.